# Rails View encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, encoding, utf-8

Using Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.8.7

I am working with an SQL Server database on a windows server with collation
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

When I go to the rails console on the Linux server with the app and query the problem record  I get
=> "Rodríguez, César"

To try to isolate the problem in my controller I tried just render :text => with the record's problem field, but on the browser I am seeing

Rodr?guez, C?sar

I believe this is an encoding issue, but I don't know how to
resolve.(and Google + Stackoverflow skills are failing me)  Given that the
source data can't be changed, what do I need to do on the rails side
to get the text to render properly?

On Chrome I have tried to manually change the encoding and no matter
which I select I can't get the text to render correctly.

Also, why would it render correctly on the console?

Answer (score 0):

character encoding is by default unicode in firefox and the same is for chrome. Just check if you tried with these.

You need to check and confirm some of the issues like 
--Meta tags in the html page. check the charset from the source of file. Change it to utf-8 in the layout and try.
--Database encoding
--Select a character set that contains mappings for all the characters that an application and its users will want to see

There can be better solutions, still give a try using Inkscape command line tool, change the text to image files and then you can display.
Encoding is handled here with no issues currently.

Comment: I did try changing the encoding to a few different ones and all gave me '?'